# YouTube Api v3: calculate youtube playlist length

Tags: youtube-api, java-18

How can i get a youtube playlist duration (the sum of all it's videos durations).

I used this endpoint to get the playlist videos :

> https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?playlistId

and it's return the videos object with all videos ids, in this case i need to make an api call to get each video length with separate api call to :

> https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos

I searched for a solution for this and found that we can make a call to previous api with all ids each id with a query param ex. id=aaaaa&id=bbbbb, but i need to be the owner of these videos to make the request.

Is there any way to get all videos with one call and without being the owner of the videos ?

Comment: For retrieving data from YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint for public and unlisted videos you don't need to be the owner of the videos. So what do you mean by *but i need to be the owner of these videos to make the request*?

Comment: Note that you  need to enumerate the playlist videos ids with [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) and to retrieve their duration with `Videos: list` so you need at least two requests and for each extra set of 50 videos ids you will need an additional request due to [`Videos: list#maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#maxResults).

Comment: I tried this api call with 3 videos : 
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&id=eIho2S0ZahI&id=c0KYU2j0TM4&id=Ks-_Mh1QhMc&key=AIzaSyBqOqOKsxj00Io35T1VqxYQo4rYgnUKEiI
The returned json was :
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "YIUPVpqNjppyCWOZfL-19bLb7uk",
  "items": [],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  }

Comment: You just leaked your YouTube Data API v3 key, please renew it. The videos ids have to be provided to `Videos: list`, it's not a correct filter for `PlaylistItems: list`. So this request should interest you instead https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=eIho2S0ZahI,c0KYU2j0TM4,Ks-_Mh1QhMc&key=KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can calculate length of any youtube playlist.

1. There is two API
2. First API will give you  id of each video
3. Using this id you can make a request to get duration of each video
   Here is both api which you are wandering around

'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=500&fields=items/contentDetails/videoId,nextPageToken,pageInfo&key=${API_KEY}&playlistId=${link}&pageToken='

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?&part=contentDetails&id=${id}&key=${API_KEY}&fields=items/contentDetails/duration
```

create an [api key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard and get API_KEY. Use it in first url and make a get request you will get all the id's.
[video id of playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiGSl.png)

Use id in second url make a request you will get duration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOi7J.png)